# Дискорд Бот не играет музыку с FFmpeg на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Дискорд Бот не проигрывает музыку когда запущен на Хероку. У меня предположение что проблема в коде, ток я не знаю как именно это исправить.

Сам ffmpeg на хероку у меня загружен, но все-одно ничего не работает.

- heroku/python
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
- https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

Часть кода

```
with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPT) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(list_of_songs[0][1], download=False)

    URL = info['url']
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPT))
```

Comment: В коде вроде-как все правильно, вы бы лучше текст ошибки предоставили. Текст ошибки у вас есть?

Comment: В консоли heroku выдает ошибку discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

Comment: Бота после установки билдпаков пробовали перезапускать?

Comment: Тоже пробовал, пропобал что-то менять в хероку, и в самом коде, но пока без результатно. Как была та же ошибка, так и осталась.